# NTPd multicast setup

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I need to setup a ntp multicast client. To be able to check of my configuration is good, I trIde to setup an NTP multicast server.

My setup :

- 2 VM of Centos 7, up to date
- I am using 2 virtual machine in virtualbox, I have setup both with promicius mode : allow all

My problems are :

- On the server, the multicast entry is reported as stratum 16; is stratum relevant for multicast? Does the client will reject this as the stratum is low? How can I force a lower stratum for a multicast server?
- My client doesn't seems to *see* my server, even if my keys file are identical and that I have trusted the key 1 on both sides.

Using instructions for orphan, it doesn't seems to lower the reported stratum for the multicast address :

```
ntpq -n -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*192.165.10.2    192.165.10.109   4 u   14   64  377    0.454    2.267   1.479
 224.0.1.1       .MCST.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

And my client still doesn't seems to be able to find a server on the 224.0.1.1 address.

I have checked on the server vm, my host machine, and on the client vm, they all see the server multicast messages (for vm : using tcpdump, for host : using wireshark).

On client, using `ntpq -n -p` will return this :

```
No association ID's returned
```

On the client, my config file have all restrict instructions commented, and I only have these (and some more like driftfile and such) :

```
multicastclient 224.0.1.1
keys /etc/ntp/keys
trustedkey 1
```

ntpd client log gives me this :

```
systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Service...
ntpd[11076]: ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Tue Jun 23 15:38:18 UTC 2020 (1)
systemd[1]: Started Network Time Service.
ntpd[11077]: proto: precision = 0.052 usec
ntpd[11077]: 0.0.0.0 c01d 0d kern kernel time sync enabled
ntpd[11077]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
ntpd[11077]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
ntpd[11077]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
ntpd[11077]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
ntpd[11077]: Listen normally on 3 enp0s3 192.165.10.107 UDP 123
ntpd[11077]: Listen normally on 4 lo ::1 UDP 123
ntpd[11077]: Listen normally on 5 enp0s3 fe80::a00:27ff:fec1:cc1 UDP 123
ntpd[11077]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
ntpd[11077]: Listen normally on 6 multicast 224.0.1.1 UDP 123
ntpd[11077]: Joined 224.0.1.1 socket to multicast group 224.0.1.1
ntpd[11077]: 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart
ntpd[11077]: 0.0.0.0 c012 02 freq_set kernel 0.000 PPM
ntpd[11077]: 0.0.0.0 c011 01 freq_not_set
ntpd[11077]: io_setbclient: Opened broadcast client on interface #3 enp0s3
```

Comment: What does `ntpq -np` return on the time server? Until you've got a decent time source nothing will synchronise to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stratum 16 indicates the NTP server does not believe it has a valid time because it has no connection to any configured time source. In order to make `ntpd` on the server system trust the system's local clock as a time source, there are two options:

- The modern method is to specify the `tos orphan` and `tos orphanwait` keywords in the `ntp.conf` file on the multicast server.

```
# If orphaned, serve others with this stratum.
tos orphan 8
# Wait for this many seconds before starting to serve others (default is 300 s)
tos orphanwait 1
```

- The older way is to tell `ntpd` to use the local clock as a fake time source on the multicast server. This configuration **should not be used together with real NTP time sources**, as it might cause `ntpd` to believe the local clock instead of the real NTP sources, unless a sufficient number of external sources have been configured and are in good enough sync with each other to out-vote the 127.127.1.0 pseudo-source (which is always perfectly in agreement with the local clock so it tends to get  excessively favored by the `ntpd` selection algorithm).

```
server 127.127.1.0 iburst
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 8
```

The IP addresses starting with `127.127.*` are special for `ntpd`: they refer to various reference clock drivers built into `ntpd`.

Both of these methods will make the system serve the UTC time based on the local unsynchronized system clock over NTP using stratum 8, so any systems with a reasonably direct connection to a real NTP time source (= stratum 7 or less) should prefer it over this one.

Using the newer way is recommended whenever your version of `ntpd` supports it, since with it you don't have to remember to remove the pseudo-source if/when you add real NTP time sources to the system.

Comment: Thank you, I must have missed something, as on the server, this doesn't seems to do anything. I will edit the question.

Comment: Was the `ntpq -n -p` output from the multicast client or the multicast server? CentOS 7 might have just old enough version of `ntpd` that its implementation of the orphan option may be buggy. Try the older way, and ensure that the multicast server has an asterisk on the leftmost column on its `ntpq -np` output before even looking at the multicast client. You might want to change the `server 127.127.1.0` line to `server 127.127.1.0 iburst` to speed up the start-up phase of `ntpd`.

Comment: On the server, I am a client of another ntp instance, could this be a problem ? It is selecting this server as preferred (like you can see in my Edit #1) and the multicast packets are received on the client vm (checked via tcpdump)

Comment: If the `ntpd -n -p` output is from the multicast server, then the line with `224.0.1.1` is saying that the multicast server is not *receiving* any NTP multicasts from other servers and so the stratum level of its multicast client function is at 16; it does not mean the server is *sending* multicasts at stratum 16. Did you add the `multicastclient 224.0.1.1` line to the multicast server too? Does the multicast server's configuration have a line like `broadcast 224.0.1.1 ttl 1`? (adjust TTL to suit your network requirements)

Comment: I didn't know that the server must be client of itself. I tried with the multicastclient enabled and the ttl 1 on the broadcast entry, but it didn't worked. Then I have changed the conf as such : `broadcast 224.0.1.1 minpoll 6 maxpoll 6 key 1 ttl 7` and after restarting the process, the client was synced immediately. Great ! Can I ask for something else ? I notied that the type is 'u' (unicast), will it ever be 'm' (multicast) ?

Comment: No, I meant that adding the client configuration to the server too might have caused confusion. But I suspect the `key 1` part was, well, the key to your success: your client was configured to trust only a particular key, and the server needed to be explicitly configured to use it on the multicasts.

Comment: So adding a multicastclient on the server is not needed ? My broadcast entry was using a key (1) without having the key keyword, maybe it was the problem.

Comment: Exactly, to both of your comments.